# Use recursive method that uses MacLaurin series to compute e^x

Tags: java, recursion

How would I write a recursive static method that uses an (n+1) term MacLaurin series to compute e^x, called e(x,n), by using the following recursive formulation:

```
e(x,0)= 1 
e(x,n)= e(x,n-1) + x^n/n!, if n>0
```

Also, my method signature needs to use the following:

```
public static double eTwo(double x, long n)
```

Been stuck for a while, any thoughts guys?

Comment: well, you could start by copying and pasting that formula into your method. That would put you just about 90% there.

Comment: Any other tips? Still kind of stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simplest solution that get on my mind, did you try it?

```
public static double eTwo(double x, long n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return eTwo(x,n-1) + Math.pow(x, n)/factorial(n);
}

public double factorial (n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A version which is likely a little more efficient would be to use a loop instead of recursion, because only a single stack frame needs to be allocated:

```
static double eTwo(double x, long n) {
    double result = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        result += Math.pow(x, (double) i) / (double) factorial(i);
    return result;
}

static long factorial(long n) {
    long result = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```